# update dom with error in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a very simple interface where a user can write an article, with a title and a text body. Here is the simplified HTML

```
<ng-form role="form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="article.title" ng-required />
  <textarea ng-model="article.content" ng-required></textarea>
</ng-form>
```

Then in my controller for the page:

```
article.controller("write", ["$scope", "$location", "Article",
  function($scope, $location, Article) {
    $scope.article = new Article();
    $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.article.$save(function(data) {
        // if successful, direct them to the article they wrote
        $location.path("/archive/" + data._id);
      }, function(fail) {
        // I need to handle the error here
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

There could be a few errors, such as the very standard ones, but also for example if the title is not unique, it will deny it on the back end.

I'm a bit confused as to how to update the DOM on receiving an error. I imagine `$scope.$broadcast` would be used in the handler. How can I make an error handler that updates the dom to show the error?

Comment: you should use directive to do dom update, Unless you just wanna use ng-show to control the message part.

Comment: `function(fail) { $scope.error = fail; }` and `<span ng-show="error" ng-bind="error | json"></span>.`